# How to show a message for other team members (laravel 9)

Tags: laravel, alert

I'm trying to get a message to show for all members of a team in Laravel once a job is created. But I've no idea how to do this. As an example say i create a job where anyone in my team can work on it. I wish to show a message on my team-mates app the next time they view the page. Something like 'Craig created job 765675. click here to open the job.'.

I realise that `Session::flash( 'message', $theMessage );` isn't the way to go as this would only be for myself right? How can I do this for other users (if I can that is).

Comment: Maybe sweet alart will work??

Comment: I'm not using sweet allert in this project but I would still need something like what pmcpimentel is suggesting anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a basic notification system, if you are going to share notifications to X users. A basic `notifications` table with `route` / `title` / `message` fields and a `user_notifications` table with `user_id` / `is_read` should work for basic notifications. As an example, when you create a new job you can fire a `JobCreated` event that creates 1 new notification with the information you want & adds X users (based on a team or anything else) to it. When you access your application you can request the current notifications for that authenticated user.

Comment: When I looked at this I thought that sounds a bit more than needed but after thinking some more it is pretty much exactly what i need and can be added into my layout blade. I could remove them once they have been 'handled'.